# Why does Spring Boot have @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")?

Tags: spring-kafka

about KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration

Why exactly the condition by name? because of this, several bins appear in the context.

Answer (score 0):

The `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` name is used in the `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the default {@link org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory}.
 */
public static final String DEFAULT_KAFKA_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory";.
```

Since we cannot use a dependency injection for `BeanPostProcessor`, there is a convention in spring-kafka to just specify a bean name which has some default. So, by convention Spring Boot auto-configures one specific for us.

Not sure what is your concern about `several beans`, but you indeed can have configured `@KafkaListener` for specific `containerFactory` and not rely on a default one.